# Creating an JS function getTransform(from, to) to return 2x3 affine matrix for use in JS canvas context function transform(a, b, c, d, e, f)

Tags: javascript, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I need a JS function getTransform(from, to) to take 4 'from' points and 4 'to' points and return a 3x3 affine matrix to be used with the JS canvas context function transform(a, b, c, d, e, f). The problem is this is just an affine transformation, so parallel lines will always be preserved, which wont work for my use case.

For example, 'from' points [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)] and 'to' points [(0.25, 0), (0.75, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)] can't produce the correct matrix, because the parallel lines in 'from' become unparallel in 'to'.

What I believe could be a solution is that the getTransform function changes the points 'from' and 'to' so they are alike in terms of parallel lines, but so then the matrix returned still correctly transforms the original points.

Here is my current code:

```
matrix = getTransform(
  [new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 16), new Point(16, 16), new Point(16, 0)],
  [p1, p2, p3, p4]
);
  
  
context.save();
context.transform(...matrix);
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
context.restore();
```

And the current getTransform function:

```
function getTransform(from, to) {
  let A = [];
  let B = [];

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let x1 = from[i].x; let y1 = from[i].y;
    let x2 = to[i].x;   let y2 = to[i].y;

    A.push([x1, y1, 1, 0, 0, 0]);
    A.push([0, 0, 0, x1, y1, 1]);
    B.push(x2);
    B.push(y2);
  }

  let X = math.multiply(math.transpose(A), A);
  let Y = math.multiply(math.transpose(A), B);
  let result = math.multiply(math.inv(X), Y);

  let [a, c, e, b, d, f] = [
    result[0], result[1], result[2],
    result[3], result[4], result[5]
  ];

  return [a, b, c, d, e, f];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To completely construct an affine transformations, one needs *three* points.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes, but my application needs to transform 4 points using the context.transform() function. Is there any other way I could achieve this result?

Comment: There's a unique affine transformation which sends 3 points to 3 points. If the 4th 'from' point is not mapped to the 4th 'to' point by the transformation issued from the first three points, that cannot work.